# 6to4 behind NAT

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

I've got problem with 6to4 tunnel on Ubuntu.
My PC's public address is `178.42.231.125`, my pivate address is `192.168.100.10`
Configuration of tunnel:

```
ip tunnel add 6to4 mode sit ttl remote any local 178.42.231.125
ip link set dev 6to4 up
ip -6 addr add 2002:b22a:e77d::1/16 dev 6to4 # I used public address to calculate b22a:e77d
ip -6 route add 2000::/3 via ::192.88.99.1 dev 6to4 metric 1
```

And now I try `ping6 ipv6.google.com` and destination unreachable

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

For 6to4 to work behind NAT, you need to have your NAT:ing router forward all "protocol 41" (6to4) traffic to your Ubuntu computer. Exactly how you set that up will depend on the router.

You also wont be able to have more than one computer speaking 6to4 behind the router, for this reason. But that computer can announce it's 6to4 prefix on the local network and route it to other computers there, if necessary.

You might also want to take note of the fact that a large part of the operator community considers 6to4 broken and wants it to be [deprecated](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-troan-v6ops-6to4-to-historic-00) and "turned off". You'd probably be better off with a "real" IPv6 tunnel from [HE](http://tunnelbroker.net/), if you can't get native. When settings up such a tunnel you'll still need to set up proto 41 forwarding in your router.

Comment: +1. More over, if you opt for AYIYA with SIXX you wouldn't need to worry about NAT at all. I was running this configuration for about a year without any problems.

Comment: I use ubuntu as router. How to forward 41 protocol?

Comment: If you use Ubuntu as your router (the one with the public IP), then you should probably set up 6to4 there instead of on your other PC.

Comment: What do you mean that I should probably set up 6to4 there instead of on your other PC?

Comment: I think we are misunderstanding each other. Can you clarify your network layout, preferable with a diagram?

Comment: My network (IP addresses are exaple)


http://hotfile.com/dl/124504911/6fd3e82/network.JPG.html

Here is the network(Sorry but I've got too small reputation to upload image here)

Thanks for every help

Comment: Did You see that?

Comment: Yes. Beyond being annoying (15 sec wait, captcha, come on?) it explains nothing.

Comment: OK try here http://www.freeimagehosting.net/c4be4. I want to connect with f.e. ipv6.google.com using this scenerio.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say you have to make a NAT rule of protocol 41 to your Ubuntu. I only want to add that maybe this is not the best idea. There are IPv6 transitions protocols designed to work specifically behind a NAT device and give you a routable IPv6 address automatically.

Check out about [Teredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling) and the software [Miredo](http://www.remlab.net/miredo/) for your linux.

Answer (score 0):

OK, never mind about that look here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/10335694.jpg/. I creat 4 VM with Ubuntu. Two are routeres, two hostes. Hosts try to connect.

`Config R1:`

`ip -4 addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev eth0`

`ip tunnel add tun6to4 mode sit ttl 64 remote any local 1.1.1.1`
`ip link set dev tun6to4 up`
`ip -f inet6 addr add 2002:101:101::1/16 dev tun6to4`
`ip -f inet6 route add 2002::/16 dev tun6to4 metric 1`

`echo 1 >/pros/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

`echo 1 >/pros/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding`

`Config R2:`

`ip -4 addr add 1.1.1.2/24 dev eth0`

`ip tunnel add tun6to4 mode sit ttl 64 remote any local 1.1.1.2`
`ip link set dev tun6to4 up`
`ip -f inet6 addr add 2002:101:102::1/16 dev tun6to4`
`ip -f inet6 route add 2002::/16 dev tun6to4 metric 1`

`echo 1 >/pros/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

`echo 1 >/pros/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding`

`Config A:`

`ip -6 addr add 2002:101:101::3/48 dev eth0`

`Config B:`

`ip -6 addr add 2002:101:102::3/48 dev eth0`

I try ping host B on VM with host A and i can't. What may be wrong?

Comment: What do You thinking?